# CodeIgniter still show error whenever i already set encryption_key in config file

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, compiler-errors

I don't know where is my mistake, when i upgrade CI 2.2.x into 3.0.x, I follow the instruction here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html, something error happen.

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> In order to use the encryption class requires that you set an
>   encryption key in your config file.

Based on many suggestions, i have to set encryption_key in config file (application/config/config.php) I change it like this

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'My Secret Key';
```

But, I still got same error.

Do you have any idea or i has did other mistakes?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

CI version 3.0.x has made some changed of files on system folder. Especially for my case above, i found the solution.

Please see this function on system/library/Encrypt.php

```
public function get_key($key = '')
{
    if ($key === '')
    {
        if ($this->encryption_key !== '')
        {
            return $this->encryption_key;
        }

        $key = config_item('encryption_key');

        if ( ! strlen($key))
        {
            show_error('In order to use the encryption class requires that you set an encryption key in your config file.');
        }
    }

    return md5($key);
}
```

on line

```
$key = config_item('encryption_key');
```

var `$key`never return your encryption_key on config file (application/config/config.php)
It just show empty string although you already input your key string.
Change that line to

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$key = $CI->config->item('encryption_key');
```

and var `$key` will show your key string on config file (application/config/config.php)

Thanks